# how to run own function in every element in a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataset, element

I have create my own function.

```
MYCV=function(x1,x2){
 #step 2 create mean diff
  
  meandiff1=function(x1,x2){
    mean1=colMeans(x1)
    mean2=colMeans(x2)
    beza=mean1-mean2
    return(beza)
  }
  
  bezamean=meandiff1(x1,x2)
}
```

From this function, I want to run in a multiple data sets which then give 1 single value for each dataset. As for the function for multiple datasets, here is the function.

```
#create function simulation
#multivariate random data
a=0
variance=1
g1=5
g2=5
mn=0
covar=matrix(c(variance,a,a,a,variance,a,a,a,variance),ncol=3)
covar


# 5 sets of simulation data 
k = 5


library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(123)
#This creates a vector of 5 NA values

listofdfs <- list()


for (i in 1:k){ #this starts your for loop
  #data = c(rmvnorm(n=g1,mean=c(mn,mn,0),sigma=covar),
  x1 = rmvnorm(n=g1,mean=c(mn,mn,0),sigma=covar)
  x2 = rmvnorm(n=g2,mean=c(mn,mn,0),sigma=covar) #generate your data
  data = list(x1=x1,x2=x2) # to make each sub element to x1 and x2
  df = data
  listofdfs[[i]]=df  #Now you can see the simulation value from 5 simulation process
  
}
listofdfs
```

My problem here is how to run my own function in every element in `listofdfs` here?

Comment: Untested: `lapply(listofdfs, \(df) do.call(MYCV, df))`

Comment: Your `MYCV ` does not return any thing  , you have to return values from it.

Comment: @Roland, can you please explain on this part--> \(df) do.call(MYCV, df)). the function of \(df). as for do.call, the function is to give the value of each df

Comment: `do.call(foo, list(x, y))` is the same as `foo(x, y)`. `do.call` constructs the call and evaluates it. Study `help("do.call")`.

Comment: Thank you @Roland. I'm able to obtain the value using the function you give. I do use lappy() before butI keep getting an error. I am sure the input in the lappy function that I insert is wrong.